# Delay after action in console

Tags: java, android

Im making a simple software that imitates human reaction to words ( sounds weird I know..) and Im stuck at the part where I make the console pause after receiving a response from the program. So for example: I type "Hi" , the program displays "Hello" afterwards, and after that Hello I need the console to pause for say 2 seconds, so that I can't for example type anything in the console during the pause.

Answer (score 0):

this is missing some information on how you actually do this ? aka code.

Simply thrown in: use Thread.sleep (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Comment: This is a really bad solution and will halt the UI thread for the duration of the sleep - returning in your application not responding to any UI events like touches.

Comment: ah my bad - didn't see the android label, so assumed not to have an ui. Nevertheless I assume in android one can sleep the right thread to avoid an unresponsive ui

Answer (score 0):

I assume somewhere in your code there's an event that triggers when the program replies with "Hello". Declare a class variable like this:

```
private long replyDelayTimer;
```

After that, in your code where it sends the message (when you click the submit button, or press the enter key on keyboard), check if the replyDelayTimer has timed out already:

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - replyDelayTime > 2000) { //2000 ms = 2 seconds
     doThingsWithMessage();
     replyDelayTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
} else {
    Toast.makeText("Please wait " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - replyDelayTime) + " ms." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```